# how to set a variable in an angular factory once it's available?

Tags: angularjs

I created a factory in angular that communicates with an API. For that API I need to pass in an 'x-token' custom header with every request, and that token is created in localstorage once a user has logged in.

I notice that the factory thinks that the token is null, probably because the factory gets loaded before the users has logged in?

Is there a way to populate this token in the factory after a user has logged in or is there a better way to handle this?

```
app.factory('apiFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    $http.defaults.headers.common['x-token'] = localStorage.getItem("token");
```

In the code sample above, the factory says that the x-token is null while it's definitely in localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right that the token is null because the factory gets loaded before the user has logged in.

There are a few ways of handling this. You could loosely couple the setting of the header value using `$rootScope.$on` event call, something like this:

```
app.factory("apiFactory", [
  "$http", function($http) {
    return $rootScope.$on("loginSuccess", function() {
      $http.defaults.headers.common["x-token"] = localStorage.getItem("token");
    });
  }
]);
```

You would then `$broadcast` the event when the user successfully logs in (after setting `localStorage`).

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('loginSuccess');
```

An alternative would be to tightly couple the setting of the header value via some kind of an `apiFactory.setHeader(token)` method. You could then inject your apiFactory into the controller or service that does the logging in and call the method upon success.